# NoneType Object has no attribute “get_text” — Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I was doing some web scraping from amazon and I came across this error (mentioned in title).

**This is my code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib


URL = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/UGREEN-Adapter-Samsung-Oneplus- Blackview/dp/B072V9CNTK/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?keywords=otg+cable&qid=1578610622&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEzRzRRUUdaR05RVlRJJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNjExNjM4MVI4NVZaTFlYTlhGSCZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMjg1MTU0OEhROERWQTBSRFAzJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==' 

headers = {
"User Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
converted_price = float(price[0:3])



def check_price():
    print(soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text())
    converted_price = float(price[0:3])
    if(converted_price < 7.00):
        send_mail()
```

Comment: Can you try `print(soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the page is dynamically loaded using javascript. You can use selenium to get the html code of the website, like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

URL = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/UGREEN-Adapter-Samsung-Oneplus- Blackview/dp/B072V9CNTK/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?keywords=otg+cable&qid=1578610622&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEzRzRRUUdaR05RVlRJJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNjExNjM4MVI4NVZaTFlYTlhGSCZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMjg1MTU0OEhROERWQTBSRFAzJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ=='

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(URL)

time.sleep(5)

page = driver.page_source

driver.close()
```

Thus, here is the full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

URL = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/UGREEN-Adapter-Samsung-Oneplus- Blackview/dp/B072V9CNTK/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?keywords=otg+cable&qid=1578610622&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEzRzRRUUdaR05RVlRJJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNjExNjM4MVI4NVZaTFlYTlhGSCZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMjg1MTU0OEhROERWQTBSRFAzJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ=='

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(URL)

time.sleep(5)

page = driver.page_source

driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')
title = soup.find(id="productTitle")
price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice")

print(soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text())
```

Output:

```
£6.99
```

Comment: Try specifying the tag name (i.e div/span/input/a)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223446/discussion-between-msharay015-and-sushil).